# Zend + Pop Up's balloons on Server Problem

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite, balloon, popup-balloons

Dear Friends from Stackoverflow,

Please help me with a problem that i'm having when uploading my project to
the server.

I'm using pop up's balloons (http://mckay.cshl.edu/balloons.html) for a project using Zend FW and it works fine on my localhost. 
(I'm using MAMP on MacOSX) but when I upload the webpage to the server, the text inside the balloons is displayed but the images that form the balloon are not, so somehow the js does not recognize the url to the images (the path it's correct, i've checked several times).

The server is an Ubuntu 9.04 virtual machine from rackspace.com, running a LAMP server.

I'm using the REWRITE function in Apache, so i guess maybe that's the problem.
The rewrite configuration is set up using a .htaccess file with the following content:

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule !.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ index.php

Does anyone knows what the problem might be?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the file permissions for the images? maybe they are set incorrectly.